# boost::filesystem::exists crashs

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I'm using boost 1.52, when i'm trying to get a file from a network drive that i don't have permissions to read from. I get an exception, after using `boost::filesystem::exists(fileName)`

Is there a work around nicer than just doing `try, catch` at every place?

I have switched back for my old code for now:

```
bool FileExists(const char* fileName)
{
    struct stat my_stat;
    return (stat(fileName, &my_stat) == 0);
}

//boost Exists throws exception if there are no permissions for share folder
bool FileExists(const std::string& fileName)
{
    return FileExists(fileName.c_str());
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use the functions you are using now, replacing `stat` with `boost::filesystem::exists` along with the necessary exception handling?  Then you don't have to use try-catch at every place.  It's isolated in that function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [overload](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#exists) that does not throw.

```
bool exists(const path& p, system::error_code& ec) noexcept;
```

You will want to check the output parameter however, so this may be more work than catching an exception. It depends what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: i'm just trying to get a config file. and i want to check if it exists before starting to parse it, and also if i have permission to read it from the network drive

Comment: Do You realize the inherent race condition with that idea? The file could be removed after exists returns but before you parse it.

Comment: yes, however it is a simple system. and the users are aware of this issue. the other issue I want to address here is permissions.