# How to check if file exists in C++ in a portable way?

Tags: c++, c, file, posix, portability

Currently I use this code to check if file exists on `Windows` and `POSIX`-compatible OSes (Linux, Android, MacOS, iOS, BlackBerry 10):

```
bool FileExist( const std::string& Name )
{
#ifdef OS_WINDOWS
    struct _stat buf;
    int Result = _stat( Name.c_str(), &buf );
#else
    struct stat buf;
    int Result = stat( Name.c_str(), &buf );
#endif
    return Result == 0;
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Does this code have any pitfalls? (maybe an OS where it cannot be compiled)
2. Is it possible to do it in a truly portable way using only C/C++ standard library?
3. How to improve it? Looking for canonical example.

Comment: What is the purpose of checking if it exists, e.g. are you going to open the file if it exists, or print an error message, or something else?

Comment: It should work fine.  I would specifically check for both Windows and POSIX with the default being something POSIX-like.  You should probably have a project-specific OS define as well, as these names themselves might change from system to system.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: printing an error message is one of the usecases.

Comment: Well, one portable way to check if a file exists is `ifstream f(name.c_str()); return f.is_open();` - doesn't require any `#if` or similar either. But my point was that if you are going to open the file later, then you may just as well open it directly - if that doesn't work, then given an error.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: opening a file is a bad idea - it can exist but open by another process in an unshared way.

Comment: I used access for testing existence. I have no idea if it is better. I actually think it is easier as you have done. Example: if (access("file", F_OK) == 0) ... It can be done on windows and linux.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong your `Result == 0` "skips"
`ENAMETOOLONG` , `ENAMETOOLONG`, errors etc. as per [this](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat).

Comment: @P0W: it looks like a potential pit-fall. Could you summarize it as an answer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because C++ is also tagged, I would use `boost::filesystem`:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

bool FileExist( const std::string& Name )
{
     return boost::filesystem::exists(Name);
}
```

**Behind the scenes**

Apparently, boost is using `stat` on POSIX and `DWORD attr(::GetFileAttributesW(FileName));` on Windows (Note: I've extracted the relevant parts of code here, it could be that I did something wrong, but this should be it).

**Basically, besides return value, boost is checking errno value in order to check if file really does not exist, or your stat failed for a different reason.**

```
#ifdef BOOST_POSIX_API

struct stat path_stat;
if (::stat(p.c_str(), &path_stat)!= 0)
{
  if (ec != 0)                            // always report errno, even though some
    ec->assign(errno, system_category());   // errno values are not status_errors

  if (not_found_error(errno))
  {
    return fs::file_status(fs::file_not_found, fs::no_perms);
  }
  if (ec == 0)
    BOOST_FILESYSTEM_THROW(filesystem_error("boost::filesystem::status",
      p, error_code(errno, system_category())));
  return fs::file_status(fs::status_error);
}

#else
     DWORD attr(::GetFileAttributesW(p.c_str()));
     if (attr == 0xFFFFFFFF)
     {
         int errval(::GetLastError());
         if (not_found_error(errval))
         {
             return fs::file_status(fs::file_not_found, fs::no_perms);
         }
     }   
#endif
```

`not_found_error` is defined separately for Windows and for POSIX:

Windows:

```
bool not_found_error(int errval)
  {
    return errval == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
      || errval == ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND
      || errval == ERROR_INVALID_NAME  // "tools/jam/src/:sys:stat.h", "//foo"
      || errval == ERROR_INVALID_DRIVE  // USB card reader with no card inserted
      || errval == ERROR_NOT_READY  // CD/DVD drive with no disc inserted
      || errval == ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER  // ":sys:stat.h"
      || errval == ERROR_BAD_PATHNAME  // "//nosuch" on Win64
      || errval == ERROR_BAD_NETPATH;  // "//nosuch" on Win32
  }
```

POSIX:

```
bool not_found_error(int errval)
  {
    return errno == ENOENT || errno == ENOTDIR;
  }
```

Comment: +1 for Boost. But using Boost only for this function (we don't use Boost for anything else) is a bit greedy.

Comment: Maybe you can expand your answer by explaining what is inside ``boost::filesystem::exists``? It can be a good answer.

Comment: @SergeyK.: The insides are similar to your code, with different implementations for different platforms. The library (which is due to become part of the standard library next year) provides a portable interface to that nastiness.

Comment: @SergeyK. Added description!

Comment: @SergeyK:  The insides are abstracted a bit, but is wrapped up in the `boost::file_status` class, which is created (in the call above - passing in a string path) by calling the `detail::status` function.  In the end, it ends up doing something very similar to what you have.  Instead of rewriting it, you can statically link to the boost libraries (which will only pull in what you are actually using), so it wouldn't be "greedy" to make use of it (even for just this feature) - it would be reusing tested code.

Comment: This is a nice answer!

Comment: @ZacHowland: the comment looks like an answer actually. Don't be shy, just add it!

Comment: @SergeyK:  I would, except it would just be a duplicate telling you to use a tested library that already exists that does exactly what you want already :)

Answer (score 4):

I perosnally like to just try to open the file:

```
bool FileExist( const std::string& Name )
{
     std::ifstream f(name.c_str());  // New enough C++ library will accept just name
     return f.is_open();
}
```

should work on anything that has files [not required by the C++ standard] and since it's using C++ `std::string`, I don't see why `std::ifstream` should be a problem.

Comment: Opening a file is a bad idea - it can exist but open by another process in an unshared way.

Comment: I'm not sure there is any way that is 100% fool proof - the file may also exist right now, and be deleted the next time this process gets to run. Or it may belong to a different user, so we don't have rights to open (or `stat`, etc) it. Any "file exists" method is advisory at best. If the knowledge of whether it exists is for the purpose of "avoid saving over an existing file", then inability to open the file is not a problem, because you also can't open the file for writing a line or three later [aside from race-conditions, of course - by any method will have that].

Comment: But the question was how to improve the existing code. Your code removes ``#ifdef`` but adds another assumption. This is not an improvement, it is a trade-off.

Comment: It is a trade-off - it improves portability and removes a dependency on the system having `stat` or `_stat` (which some OS's may not have).

Comment: Can you explain under what circumstance the "false negative" of "file is open by another process" is a big problem?

Comment: I.e. comparing the content of the target folder before copying files there.

Comment: @SergeyK. But that will fail if the file is open and in use anyway, so I don't see why that is a reason to object to this method. If the file can't be opened for reading, it certainly can't be opened for writing either. But my point is that this is portable. If other aspects are more important than portability, then don't use it.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: +1 for nice elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

1. Does this code have any pitfalls? (maybe an OS where it cannot be compiled)

`Result == 0` "skips" `ENAMETOOLONG` , `ELOOP`, errors etc. as per [this](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat)

I can think of this : `ENAMETOOLONG` path is too long as:-

In many cases ,during a recursive scan, the sub-folder/directories keep on increasing, if path is "too" long it may result into this error, but still file do exists !

Similar cases might happen with other errors too.

Also,

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15324947/1870232),
I'ld prefer to use the overloaded `boost::filesystem::exists` method

`bool exists(const path& p, system::error_code& ec) noexcept;`

Comment: @SergeyK. Not sure, may be we can try changing directory on each recurs and then start a scan.

Comment: @SergeyK. See how boost did it - basically - besides return value, you need to check last error code set.